# Threading Around a Blocking Read

Tags: ruby, linux, multithreading, joystick

I'm doing some joystick programming in Ruby on Linux using a Ruby extension which wraps the basic functionality of joystick.h. Getting a joystick event is a blocking read by default, but I don't want that to interrupt the game loop.

Currently I'm hacking around it by making non-blocking calls to the joystick and running that in a really fast loop. That works, but it also makes the script use 100% CPU because I want the joystick events as close to real time as possible.

I'm trying to do something like

```
input = Thread.new do
  while e = joystick.event
    @event = e
  end
end

main = Thread.new do
  while true
    sleep 0.1
    puts @event
  end
end
```

But even then, the `joystick.event` call blocks the main thread. Am I totally misunderstanding how Ruby threads work, or how joysticks work on Linux? Or is there a totally different way of approaching this that is better?

Comment: Is joystick.event a native extension? You're likely encountering the [Global Interpreter Lock (GIL)](http://www.igvita.com/2008/11/13/concurrency-is-a-myth-in-ruby/).

Comment: It isn't native. But that method just wraps a call to the C `read` function - which is what's blocking. I'm not sure if the GIL is the problem, because I've had success using threads to get around other blocking calls before.

Comment: Further investigation: I think it might be the GIL. I need to make use of rb_thread_blocking_region

Comment: You might want to checkout [Rubygame::Joystick](http://docs.rubygame.org/rdoc/2.6.2/classes/Rubygame/Joystick.html). I haven't used it but they have an event queue and are at version 2.6 something.  I'm betting they've already addressed blocking issues. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to make the read call in the C extension using `rb_thread_blocking_region`. Works perfectly now!